# Does anyone know a function to determine if a Point exists within a polygon?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

Does anyone know a function to determine if a Point exists within a polygon?

Edit: I'm using C# with ArcEngine10.

Comment: do you mean function in a spatial database or some API with spatial functions (if so, which language)?

Comment: [this post has a complete example for do this.][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66141/how-to-use-the-irelationaloperator-interface-to-check-if-a-point-feature-within/138362#138362

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [IRelationalOperator2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRelationalOperator2_Interface/002m00000330000000/) you can cast your polygon to that Interface and use the [contains](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Contains_Method/002m00000340000000/) method.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Arc, take a look at Graphics Gems IV
http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/

there are 2 articles with code for the point in polygon problem