# Determining if mouse click falls within polygon using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon drawn on top of a layer using the graphicsContainer of the current activeView, then I want to be able to show a custom context menu if the user right clicks INSIDE the polygon. So I have to figure out a way to determine if the mouse click falls within the polygon. I have tried to use the IRelationalOperator2 as suggested in this question [Does anyone know a function to determine if a Point exists within a polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/does-anyone-know-a-function-to-determine-if-a-point-exists-within-a-polygon), but I can't seem to get it working properly. Here is what I have so far:

```
System.Drawing.Point screenMousePoint = System.Windows.Forms.Form.MousePosition;
IPoint screenPoint = new Point();
screenPoint.X = screenMousePoint.X;
screenPoint.Y = screenMousePoint.Y;

IPoint mapPoint = this.controller.GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates(screenPoint, activeView);

// this.currentDefinedArea is a polygon
IRelationalOperator2 relation = this.currentDefinedArea as IRelationalOperator2;

if (relation.Contains(mapPoint))
{
    // Show context menu
}
```

---

The "GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates" method looks like this, and it's one of the snippets that is included in arcobjects:

```
public IPoint GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates(IPoint screenPoint, IActiveView activeView)
    {
        if (screenPoint == null || screenPoint.IsEmpty || activeView == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
        IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

        return displayTransformation.ToMapPoint((System.Int32)screenPoint.X, (System.Int32)screenPoint.Y);
    }
```

---

I found out what was causing the above code to fail. Using:

```
System.Drawing.Point screenMousePoint = System.Windows.Forms.Form.MousePosition;
```

...gives a different set of X, Y coordinates than using the MouseEventArgs provided by the OnMouseDown method. Don't know why I wasn't using them in the first place...here's how my working code looks:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    if (arg.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (this.controller.CurrentDefinedArea != null)
        {
            IPoint screenPoint = new Point();
            screenPoint.X = arg.X;
            screenPoint.Y = arg.Y;

            IPoint mapPoint = this.controller.GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates(screenPoint, activeView);

            IRelationalOperator2 relation = this.controller.CurrentDefinedArea as IRelationalOperator2;

            if (relation.Contains(mapPoint))
            {
                this.controller.CreateContextMenu(ArcMap.Application);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the spatial reference of the mapPoint match that of the polygon?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the transformation to map coordinates is correct? It is very rarely done from the screen coordinates, but instead from the physical coordinates of the activeview window. These are not the same unless the active view fits the whole screen.

Comment: @Kirk: The polygon has a SRID of 25832 and so has the mapPoint. That means they have the same spatial reference right?...sorry still very new to this...

Comment: @Petr: I'm not really sure how to confirm the transformation to map coordinates...

Comment: You can display a message box with the transformed coordinates and compare them to those displayed in ArcMap's status bar.

Comment: From the look of the GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates, this will not work. You are indeed using pixel coordinates of the whole screen (returned by MousePosition), but IDisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint expects physical coordinates relative to the display's window. First, you will need to convert them before passing to ToMapPoint.

Comment: If you are developing a tool (ITool), most methods like ITool.OnMouseDown, ITool.OnMouseMove etc will give you physical coordinates in the correct space through their arguments (x, y), which you can directly pass to IDisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint.

Comment: @Petr: woops your comments was hidden, so I didn't see them...ended up using the arguments of the OnMouseDown method as you suggested, is now working :)

Answer (score 4):

As Peter Krebs has suggested on mouse down use IDisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint to assign the XY info to a point graphic.  You can then use that graphic as a selector against your polygon layer.

```
public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, System.Int32 X, System.Int32 Y)
{
    //MyBase.OnMouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y)
    try {
        IMxApplication pMxApp = null;
        IActiveView ActiveView = default(IActiveView);

        pMxApp = (IMxApplication)m_App;

        m_MxDoc = (IMxDocument)m_App.Document;
        m_mxDocument = (MxDocument)m_App.Document;
        ActiveView = (IActiveView)(Map)m_MxDoc.FocusMap;

        IMap pMap = default(IMap);
        ISpatialReference pSpatialRef = default(ISpatialReference);

        pMap = m_MxDoc.FocusMap;
        pSpatialRef = pMap.SpatialReference;

        IScreenDisplay m_pDisplay = ActiveView.ScreenDisplay;

        m_pDisplay.StartDrawing(m_pDisplay.hDC, Convert.ToInt16(esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache));
        ISimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbolClass();

        ISymbol symbol = simpleMarkerSymbol as ISymbol;
        // Dynamic Cast
        m_pDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
        IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = m_pDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

        // X and Y are in device coordinates
        m_Point = displayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);

        m_pDisplay.DrawPoint(m_Point);
        m_pDisplay.FinishDrawing();

        SelectFeature();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " + Constants.vbCrLf + ex.ToString());
    }

}



public void SelectFeature()
{
    //SelectFeature
    try {
        ILayer pLayer = default(ILayer);
        IActiveView pActiveView = default(IActiveView);
        IEnvelope pEnvelope = default(IEnvelope);
        ISpatialFilter pSF = default(ISpatialFilter);
        IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = default(IEnumLayer);

        m_MxDoc = (IMxDocument)m_App.Document;
        m_mxDocument = (MxDocument)m_App.Document;
        m_map = (Map)m_MxDoc.FocusMap;

        pActiveView = (IActiveView)m_map;
        if (m_map.LayerCount == 0)
            return;

        pEnumLayer = m_map.Layers;

        pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next;
        while (!(pLayer == null)) {
            if (pLayer.Name == "My Polygon Layer") {
                m_FLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
            } else {
                return;
            }
            pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next;
        }

        m_FSel = (IFeatureSelection)m_FLayer;
        //Expand the points envelope to give better search results
        pEnvelope = m_MxDoc.CurrentLocation.Envelope;
        pEnvelope.Expand(m_MxDoc.SearchTolerance, m_MxDoc.SearchTolerance, false);
        pSF = new SpatialFilter();
        pSF.Geometry = pEnvelope;
        pSF.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
        pSF.GeometryField = m_FLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;

        //Refresh the old selection to erase it
        //pActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, Nothing, Nothing)
        //Perform the selection using a point created on mouse down
        m_FSel.SelectFeatures(pSF, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);

        ISelectionSet pSelSet2 = default(ISelectionSet);
        // Draw all selected features.
        pSelSet2 = m_FSel.SelectionSet;

        if (pSelSet2.Count == 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("Polygon not selected");
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Polygon selected");
        }

        //Refresh again to draw the new selection
        pActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, null, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " + Constants.vbCrLf + ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks artwork21! I had a little time this morning and found out what was wrong in my original code and I got it to work.